# Get specific XML-File from document with Office.js (Word Add-In)

Tags: xml, typescript, office-js, word-addins

I want to load the  ..\customXml\item1.xml  from my document to my Word Add-In.

I tried the following:

```
var url = Office.context.document.url + '\\customXml\\item1.xml\\'

Office.context.document.customXmlParts.getByNamespaceAsync(url, (result) => {
  console.log("2");
  if (result.value.length > 0) {
    console.log("3");
    for (var i = 0; i < result.value.length; i++) {
    }
  }
 });
```

and

```
Office.context.document.customXmlParts.getByIdAsync(
  "{ABA6B192-6371-4776-85AA-46BD32014394}", (result) => {
```

the last one works perfect but I dont know how I can get the ID without opening the word document with zip.
The first one print only "2" but wont go to "3".

Does anybody know the answer?

Comment: I imagine you're using the wrong value as the Namespace. Show us the first few lines of the content of this XML document (where the declaraions are).

Comment: you are right, i was using the wrong namespace... I used now namespace = "", and with result.value[0].id I got the id I needed to use getByIdAsynch()  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely, as Cindy suggests, get the XML part by namespace. The call should look like:

```js
    Office.context.document.customXmlParts.getByNamespaceAsync("http://tempuri.org", function (eventArgs) {
        write("Found " + eventArgs.value.length + " parts with this namespace");
    });
```

please verify you are using the right namespace.
thanks!

Comment: thanks for the response, but my document has no namespace, so I had to do it like i wrote in the comment below